# Add a custom tab on the customer detail page admin panel in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add a custom tab for customer in admin panel. When admin click particular customer the page with customer information is opened. I want to add the custom tab there.

This is what i want to achieve http://www.mydons.com/how-to-add-custom-tabs-to-magento-customer-edit-page/ .

Could anyone help?Or provide some information.

Comment: You can try this http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-create-custom-tab-in-customer-view-and-load-grid-inside-admin

Comment: actually this is not what i want.This is what i want but in M2. http://www.mydons.com/how-to-add-custom-tabs-to-magento-customer-edit-page/

Comment: Ok, but in magento 2 not possible as like magento 1. Can you please tell me that which version use in magento 2 like 2.1 or other ?

Comment: Why is it not possible? I don't think so, can you explain why can't this be achieved in magento 2. Also does it matter either it is 2 or 2.1

Comment: That is possible but different way for magento 2.1.

Comment: You need to use ui-component.